# Geymotion emulator galaxy s8 no WiFi settings

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I am trying to get an emulated Galaxy S8 in GenyMotion to proxy all traffic through my Kali VM that has Burp suite (intercepting proxy) running. All tutorials say to just turn on wifi in the emulated phone and set the proxy settings there (and that is how I remembered doing it around a year ago). But I cannot turn on the WiFi in the emulated phone.

So the question is: does anyone know:

a. How to turn the WiFi on in an GenyMotion emulated Galaxy S8?

b. If a is not answerable: how to direct all traffic from the emulated phone to the proxy?

EDIT: Using a galaxy S5 emulated phone does work with wifi....

EDIT2: So it is a problem with GenyMotion and android 8.0 (as the galaxy s8 with android 7 does work with the wiredSSID wireless). I would still like to know how to set this up though! :D

Comment: So I got a reaction from Genymotion saying that the WiFi implementation as it was in android <8.0 has not yet been implemented as they were having some difficulties. SO most likely it will eventually work.